# Prevent parent trigger when click on click element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having code like this. need to prevent the div onclick when click on anchor tag.

```
<div onclick="window.open(url)">
  <p>
   .
   .
   .
  </p>
  <a href="link"/>

</div>
```

Not Duplicate question,here div tag has window.open(url), not js onclick function.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: ..... Is u r code?

Comment: Please share your whole code so can suggest you.

Answer (score 1):

### You have to first prevent default click functionality and then do like shown below

```
<div onclick="window.open(url)" class="parent_div">
  <p>
   .
   .
   .
  </p>
  <a href="link"/>

</div>



$(document).on('click', '.parent_div a', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    let url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.assign(url)
});
```